# jquery popup how do I add x close button?

Tags: jquery

I have jquery

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 

jQuery('.et_pt_item_image').click(function(){ // attach a function to elements with the class "unhide"
   jQuery(this).closest('.et_pt_item_image').find('.hidden').show(); // Look for the closest parent of this item with the class "holder" and find the hidden div, show it
   jQuery(this).closest('.et_pt_item_image').find('.hidden').delay( 800 ).hide(1000); // find the same element and close after delay, take 1000 ms to close. 
});
```

});

```
<div class="et_pt_item_image"><div class="hidden"> hello Im a popup </div></div>
```

At the moment the box is disappearing delay( 800 ).hide(1000) but I would like to have an x button on the box and have it only disappear when the x is clicked. 
How do I do this?

Comment: u wanna disappear whole box on clicking x button right ?

Comment: add an x in the html, then trigger the above code only on the click of the x.

Comment: jQuery(this).closest('.et_pt_item_image').find('.hidden').delay( 800 ).hide(1000); Should only happen on click of close button. So remove that line and add that event to button that you will place on that popup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a close button inside the popup and on click of the close button call the below script

jQuery(this).closest('.et_pt_item_image').find('.hidden').delay( 800 ).hide(1000);

Comment: I tried $('.hidden .close').on('click', function() {
  jQuery(this).closest('.et_pt_item_image').find('.hidden').delay( 800 ).hide(1000);
}); but is doesnn't work

Comment: jQuery('.hidden .close').on('click', function () {
        jQuery(this).closest('.et_pt_item_image').find('.hidden').delay(50).hide(500);
    }); worked for me. Sorry I forgot to mention it is a wordpress site.

Answer (score 3):

You may wanna do something like this:

```js
$('.box .close').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent().fadeOut();
});
```

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black
}
.box .close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.box .inner {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <div class="close">X</div>
  <div class="inner">
    This is a popup!
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I added <div class="hidden"> <div class="close">X</div> then $('.hidden .close').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent().fadeOut();
}); but where should I put it in my code in the original question to geit to work?

Answer (score 0):

define class hidden as

hidden { visible:none;}

now if you want to hide image then do $('#idofthediv').addClass('hidden') and to show $('#idofthediv').removeClass('hidden')